# AngularJS directive wrapping Kendo UI grid does not receive valid kendoEvent

Tags: angularjs, controller, kendo-ui, grid, directive

So we are trying to create displayBasket directive in order to wrap kendoGrid and other functionality. However, gridDataBound function does not receive kendoEvent. How can we fix this?

In HTML:

```
<display-basket grid-id="bb-grid" actions="bbActions" uids="uids" grid-options="bbOptions" grid-data-source-factory="bbDataSourceFactory" grid-data-source-options="bbDataSourceOptions">
</display-basket>
```

In JS:

```
bsktDirModule.directive ( 'displayBasket', function ( CBPmWebAPI, $compile, $http, $parse ) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: '<div kendo-grid id="{{gridId}}" k-options="gridOptions" k-on-data-bound="gridDataBound(kendoEvent)"></div>',
        scope: {
            actions: '=',
            uids: '=',
            gridId: '@',
            gridOptions: '=',
            gridDataSourceFactory: '=',
            gridDataSourceOptions: '='
        },
        ...
        controller: function($scope) {
            ...
            $scope.gridDataBound = function(e) {
                debugger
            }
            ...
        }
    };
});
```

Thanks,

Ivan

Answer (score 0):

Your `k-on-data-bound` content is not attached to the scope like a normal AngularJS event. You need to get back the scope to call your `gridDataBound` function.

To do so, in your `k-on-data-bound`, add `angular.element(this).scope()` before your function. It will return the scope of your current DOM node (so the one of your directive) and then you will be able to access your function.

Comment: Hi Guillame, thanks for reply. However, there are no problems in accessing function, rather, there problems in accessing kendoEvent. I can gain control in gridDataBound (debugger command stops the program), but e variable is undefined. So if your suggestion is the following modification: k-on-data-bound="angular.element(this).scope().gridDataBound(kendoEvent)", then it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Moreover, with the above modification, gridDataBound does not gain control any more. So the problem is with undefined kendoEvent.